# How is the 'or' function used in listing vairables in a function python

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to list several vairables in a function so they will all be detected:

```
    if how != 'no'or'yes':
        print"That is not a valid answer"
```

so i want the if how != to read no and yes but when i run only no is detected

Comment: no i need both yes and no to be detected and it does n't always evaluate to true

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/if-x-or-y-or-z-blah ... Specifically `if 1 in (x, y, z):` and you can rework that

Comment: Minor note: 'or' is not a function, it's a logical operator.  See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/logical_operators_example.htm.

Answer (score 0):

in your if condition:

```
if how != 'no' or 'yes':
```

you're making a wrong assessment, it's that python will understand that the value of `how` is either `no` or `yes`, like you would do in a natural language.

But what you're actually testing is whether `how` is different from `no` and whether `yes` is different from `None`:

```
if how != 'no' or 'yes' != None:
```

and the latter will always valuate to true.

The correct way to express your logic would be:

```
if how != 'no' or how != 'yes'
```

to be a bit more pythonic:

```
if not how == 'no' or not how == 'yes'
```

and the totally pythonic solution:

```
if how not in ('yes', 'no')
```

Comment: I would argue that `not how == 'yes'` is *not* "a bit more pythonic" of a way of writing the clearly defined inequality operator `!=`. Is `not x < 5` as obvious (or a bit more Pythonic) as `x >= 5`? Plus - some weird things might happen with precedence...

Comment: Minor error: if how != 'no' or how != 'yes' will always evaluate to true so that should be 'and' rather than 'or' and should read as follows: if how != 'no' and how != 'yes'.

Comment: if `how = 'perhaps', `how` will be different from `yes` and `no`. Don't be so binary! :-)

Comment: @zmo `if random.choice([True, False]):` is all everybody needs, right?

Comment: @JonClements That's a whole interpretation of the expliciteness of such expression. I consider that what's pythonic is the readability, and when you read out loud: `if how is not 'yes' or how is not 'no'` is more explicit than operators. Though I did not use the `is` operator, because its behavior on strings is an exception ;-)